# How to convert values from two different lists into a single dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping financial summary from https://www.investing.com/equities/nvidia-corp-financial-summary.
Code:

To get the ratio descriptions:

```
for element in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'float_lang_base_1'}):
    print(element)
```

The code will result in:

```
<span class="float_lang_base_1">Gross margin</span>
<span class="float_lang_base_1">Operating margin</span>
<span class="float_lang_base_1">Net Profit margin</span>
<span class="float_lang_base_1">Return on Investment</span>
<span class="float_lang_base_1">Quick Ratio</span>
<span class="float_lang_base_1">Current Ratio</span>
<span class="float_lang_base_1">LT Debt to Equity</span>
<span class="float_lang_base_1">Total Debt to Equity</span>
<span class="float_lang_base_1">Cash Flow/Share</span>
<span class="float_lang_base_1">Revenue/Share</span>
<span class="float_lang_base_1">Operating Cash Flow</span>
```

To get the values for each of ratio above:

```
for element in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'float_lang_base_2 text_align_lang_base_2 dirLtr bold'}):
    a = element.get_text()
```

results in:

```
 60.45%
 31.47%
 26.03%
 22.86%
 2.95
 3.62
 -
 49.02%
 -
 -
 16.77%
```

Now, I need to match the two, so that it will be a key value pair that can be transformed into a dataframe.

```
Gross margin : 60.45%
Operating margin: 31.47%
Net Profit margin: 26.03% 
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find main `div` tag which has both the values and iterate over that to identify other properties using `class` and append to `dict1`

```
dict1={}
for element in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'infoLine'}):
    name=element.find("span",class_="float_lang_base_1").get_text()
    value=element.find("span",class_="float_lang_base_2").get_text()
    dict1[name]=value
```

Here  you can use `pandas` to create `df` and transform `dict1` to table form data

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(dict1.items(),columns=['A','B'])
df
```

Output:

```
       A                  B
0   Gross margin        60.45%
1   Operating margin    31.47%
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Get values from two different lists into a single dictionary

```
Mykeys = ["a", "b", "c"]
Myvalues = [1, 3, 5]
print ("Mykey list: " + str(Mykeys))
print ("Myvalue list: " + str(Myvalues))
res = dict(zip(Mykeys, Myvalues))

print ("New dictionary will be : " +  str(res))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answers you could `zip()` your lists and transform into `dict()`.

---

Anyway there is an altrnative approach in selecting and extracting the information from the elements:

```
dict(list(row.stripped_strings)[::len(list(row.stripped_strings))-1] for row in soup.select('.infoLine'))
```

This one will [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) or `find_all()` elements with class `infoLine` what is the container tag of the `<span>`s. While [`.stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string-generators) extract the texts as a `ResultSet` we only have to `list slice` the first and the last element and convert it in [`dict comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to the final result.

**Be aware:** *Zipping lists or using lists at all you have to ensure, that they will have the same length, else you will get an error concerning this missmatch.*

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
url='https://www.investing.com/equities/nvidia-corp-financial-summary'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text)
dict(list(row.stripped_strings)[::len(list(row.stripped_strings))-1] for row in soup.select('.infoLine'))
```

##### Output

```
{'Gross margin': '60.45%',
 'Operating margin': '31.47%',
 'Net Profit margin': '26.03%',
 'Return on Investment': '22.86%',
 'Quick Ratio': '2.95',
 'Current Ratio': '3.62',
 'LT Debt to Equity': '-',
 'Total Debt to Equity': '49.02%',
 'Cash Flow/Share': '-',
 'Revenue/Share': '-',
 'Operating Cash Flow': '16.77%'}
```